# Snowflake window function last_value and max

Tags: sql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I have a table like this :

[image]

I want to get for each user_key the top total_listened per date / month / weekday / week

I think i need to use window functions
i can get the different date format with :

```
MONTH(stream_date) for months
WEEKDAY(stream_date) for weekday
WEEK(stream_date) for week
```

i tried with this :

```
select 
MAX(vals.total_listened_per_day) as RECORD_STREAM_DAY_TIME,
MAX(vals.total_listened_per_month) as RECORD_STREAM_MONTH_TIME,
MAX(vals.total_listened_per_week) as RECORD_STREAM_WEEK_TIME,
MAX(vals.most_active_weekday) as MOST_ACTIVE_WEEKDAY_TIME
 last_value(days.date) over (partition by user_key order by days.total_listened) as RECORD_STREAMDAY,
from
(
select user_key, stream_date as date,
sum(st.length_listened) over (partition by user_key, stream_date) as total_listened_per_day,
sum(st.length_listened) over (partition by user_key, MONTH(stream_date)) as total_listened_per_month,
sum(st.length_listened) over (partition by user_key, WEEK(stream_date)) as total_listened_per_week,
sum(st.length_listened) over (partition by user_key, DAYNAME(stream_date)) as most_active_weekday
group by 1,2
 .....
 )
```

which work for getting the amount (variables with _TIME as the end) , but it doesn't work for getting the specific day / month .... (the variables without _TIME at the end such as RECORD_STREAMDAY) , it's because of the group by , its grouped by stream_date and not month(stream_date) for example , i don't know how i can do it without doin subqueries for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic you want is:

```
select user_key,
    max(total_listened_per_day  ) as max_total_listened_per_day
    max(total_listened_per_week ) as max_total_listened_per_week,
    max(total_listened_per_month) as max_total_listened_per_month,
    max(case when rn_day   = 1 then date_trunc('day',   stream_date) end) as most_active_day,
    max(case when rn_week  = 1 then date_trunc('week',  stream_date) end) as most_active_week,
    max(case when rn_month = 1 then date_trunc('month', stream_date) end) as most_active_month
from (  
    select t.*,
        rank() over(partition by user_key order by total_listened_per_day   desc) as rn_day,
        rank() over(partition by user_key order by total_listened_per_week  desc) as rn_week,
        rank() over(partition by user_key order by total_listened_per_month desc) as rn_month
    from (
        select t.*
            sum(st.length_listened) over (partition by user_key, date_trunc('day',   stream_date)) as total_listened_per_day,
            sum(st.length_listened) over (partition by user_key, date_trunc('week',  stream_date)) as total_listened_per_week
            sum(st.length_listened) over (partition by user_key, date_trunc('month', stream_date)) as total_listened_per_month
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by user_key
```

The most inner subquery computes the window sum of listening time per day, week and month. The next subquery ranks records using that information. Finally, the outer query uses conditional aggregation to bring the corresponding durations and periods. If there are ties, the most recent period is picked.

Comment: I think it works, in the last scope i think you meant select st.* and no t.* right ?
I kinda understand the logic behind , you apply a number with rank to then identify it but how just by ordering by the target it can say this one is per day ?

Also i have another question that isn't related to this one , i want to do a top rank with percentage , 
Here just using the total_listened ordered in desc and saying these clients are in the top 5% of listeners , top 10 % , top 20 % etc 
Do you know how to ? (i saw a function rank percent but i cannot make it work that way ...)

Comment: @echo55: there is no `st` in the query (all subqueries are aliased `t`). Yes, the query attaches a rank to each row, so we can then isolate the corresponding date, using the conditional `max()`. As for your other question, it is probably worth *a new question*, providing proper sample data, desired results and explanation of the logic.